# How to import and run C++ project into Eclipse that uses its own Makefiles?

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I have a C++ project with its own Makefiles. I'm trying to import the project and run it using the Makefiles that I've already written.

I imported the project as an existing C/C++ Makefile Project with the GNU Autotools Toolchain. But after this I'm kind of lost as to how to build and run the project.

Comment: Can't you build it the same way you would if the makefile had been generated?

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar.

We build it in the console.

Then you can debug in Eclipse by setting up a Debug configuration to the application.
You do that by opening the drop down by debug, selecting Debug Configurations, then maybe you already have one, or you make a new one. And then just put the link to your Application file in the C/C++ Application windows. Then you could also disable auto build as you are building manually. Debugging then works fine.